# How to set Cookie on click of button in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, cookies

hi i am creating popup plugin in `wordpress`. For that i want to set cookie when the user click on submit button so the user when reload the page the popup will not show again and again until the cookie is not remove. This is my jQuery code

```
     $( "#sfpsubmit" ).click(function() {
                    $.cookie("sfpopup", "sf_popup", { expires: 1 });
                });

        if ($.cookie('sf_popup')) {
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            }   
        else{
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }, 3000);
        }
```

I don't know how to set cookie using `jQuery` in WordPress so i am using this way

Comment: Do you have a problem with the code? Have you checked the console for errors. Note that the `$.cookie()` method is not part of the standard jQuery library, and you will need to include that additional script in your page.

Comment: yes it is saying in console that ` $.cookie is not a function`

Comment: In that case you need to include this library in your page: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie